# Rails/Ruby how to pass 'all' as condition variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Simple question

In rails I have an ApplicationHelper method

```
def sum_customer_yearly_revenue(customer_id,  year)
  sum_customer_yearly_revenue = Sale.sum(:net_amount, :conditions => ['customer_id = ? AND financial_year = ?', customer_id, year])
end
```

In my view I then call `sum_customer_yearly_revenue(123456, 2014)`. How do I call the same method but with 'all' years. If I was using SQL it would be sum_customer_yearly_revenue(123456, *) but that returns an error. If it pass in "" it looks for a year that is empty. If I leave it blank it just errors aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def sum_customer_yearly_revenue(customer_id,  year="all")
  sales = Sale.where(customer_id: customer_id)
  sales = sales.where(year: year) if year!="all"
  sales.sum(:net_amount)
end
```

This might be useful to you. In this case if you want to retrieve sum for all year there is no necessary to pass second argument.

Comment: Thanks jbmyid this may be the way I go ahead. I have taken Amadan's advice aswell. I'll move the logic into the model and then have a series of functions with bits of logic. I may have up to 30 or 40 different functions for calculations that are just slight variations based on a variable being passed or just 'all'.

Comment: yeh off-course  it must be in model. I just gave u a direction how this can be implemented. :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the method to:

```
def sum_customer_yearly_revenue(customer_id, year = nil)
  conditions = { :customer_id => customer_id }
  conditions.merge!(:financial_year => year) if year

  Sale.sum(:net_amount, :conditions => conditions)
end
```

And call it like this:

```
sum_customer_yearly_revenue(123456)
```

Comment: would this break if I switched the nil variable onto the customer id? Ie. sum_customer_yearly_revenue(nil,2014). I could add the 'customer_id = nil' and 'if customer_id' to the method so it could be interchangeable.

Comment: The above code would not handle nil customer_id correctly. But when you start with an empty hash and only add the customer_id to the hash, when it exists (like with the year), it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Can't in this form. Make a new helper, `sum_customer_total_revenue`. Or introduce way more logic in this function, but that's not as pretty.

Also, not sure those should be any kind of helpers; that kind of stuff belongs right into a model. If you need it, make sure the model passes those information to the view by including it from a controller, not directly in a helper.

(EDIT: upvoted jbmyid; that's a better syntax to do this. However... Still think it doesn't belong in a function that's called the way it's called; still think it doesn't belong in a helper.)

Comment: Cool thanks for the advice. Still learning so appreciate the guidance.